# Why Nutch Solrdedup can not remove duplicate webpage

Tags: nutch

I have two webpages with identical contents but different in URL. One URL is started with http://www.example.com, the other started with http://example.com. After I use Solrdedup to remove duplicate data in Solr. I find that the two are remain there. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

The nutch schema defines id (= url) as the unique key. If that is not ok for you, then change it. The corresponding line in the `schema.xml` is:

```
<uniqueKey>url</uniqueKey>
```

But the better solution may be to do the following: If you can access your server by

```
http://www.example.com
```

and by

```
http://example.com
```

you should consider crawling only one of them using regex-url filters to prevent duplicates.